# wineserver fails with socket related errors

Tags: wine

Whenever I try running `winecfg` or `wine` itself I get next error:

```
sock_init: ERROR in sock_check_pollhup()
wineserver: socket: Permission denied
```

Here is my OS info:

```
$ lsb_release -dc
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Codename:       xenial

$ uname -r
4.4.0-47-generic

$ wine --version
wine-1.9.23-80-ga4ed76b
```

I've also tried `wine` version `1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14` from Ubuntu's repositories and the result was the same.

I don't know how to go about this problem, I tried reinstalling but it proved ineffective. I disabled my `apparmor` profiles but the problem persisted.

Any ideas?. I'd appreciate any help you can give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, the error was my fault.

- I (being a `systemd` newbie) issued `restart` instead of `reload`
  when restaring `apparmor` service. The right command would be
  `systemctl reload apparmor.service`.
- My `apparmor` profile for `wine` had `deny network` which was the
  reason the errors popped up. Before installing Ubuntu 16.04 I had not
  that problem. By the way, I still denied the network using `iptables`.

Every thing works now. I feel kinda embarrased, I hope at least this helps somebody out there.